# PHP CURL returning different result from CURL for Linux

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to work out why a call to a web service isn't returning the results I need.

Using CURL for Linux with

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" "https://www.thisapi.com/stuff/?status=something" > myfile.txt
```

I get the correct results, an object starting: {"object_count": 4, ...

Using PHP with libcurl and

```
$curl = curl_init();
$hdr[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
$hdr[] = 'Accept: application/json';

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $hdr);

$url = 'https://www.thisapi.com/stuff/?status=something';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

//return the data
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$results = curl_exec($curl);
```

Ignores the URL variable "status" and I get {"object_count": 8 ...

Can anyone help me to work out in which ways these two requests are not equivalent and therefore why they are not returning the same results?

Comment: How is your "something" look like? May be it should be url encoded?

Comment: @Cheery - Just text, no entities that would usually need url encoding. Literally "status=active"

Comment: And also, why do you have `$hdr[] = 'Content-type: application/json';`? Are you sending something to the remote server?

Comment: @Cheery - dammit, you're right. I'd reused the code from another file and just had "code blindness". Cheers for the extra pair of eyes - I've been banging my head on that one for ages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second case you have an additional header you are sending - `Content-type: application/json`. Perhaps this is causing the API endpoint to respond differently, ignoring the parameter in the URL, as it is expecting something in JSON format.